# Get IP v4 address

Tags: powershell, networking, ip

i get the IP address with the following command, i've putted -Match because sometimes it's Ethernet or Ethernet0, Ethernet1, i would like to excluse every network adapteur who come with ip LIke 127.0.0.1 or 169* in my following where, can you help me to do that ? thanks.

`Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | where Interfacealias -Match 'Ethernet'`

get only 1 IP, not 127 and 169

Comment: `Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet |Where PrefixOrigin -ne WellKnown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addresses from the reserved parts of the address space - like the localhost loopback (127.0.0.0/8) and link-locals (169.254.0.0/16) - will be marked with `PrefixOrigin: WellKnown` - you can use this to filter them out:

```
$actualAddresses = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet |Where PrefixOrigin -ne WellKnown
```

If you want only the first available result, use `Select-Object -First 1`:

```
$firstActualAddress = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet |Where PrefixOrigin -ne WellKnown |Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: Ty. i've just change to Ethernet* to get ethernet0 or ethernet1 if the name is a bit different. it works. ty.

Comment: @Fellerson Great to hear. You can also combine multiple filter conditions with `Where-Object` if you want, eg.: `... |Where-Object { $_.PrefixOrigin -ne 'WellKnown' -and $_.InterfaceAlias -like "whatever*" }` :)